# Heathrow change in terminal (from 5 to 3) flight UK Border control check?

Tags: uk, transit-visas, lhr

I'm F1 student. I am traveling from NYC to Spain via London. My connecting flight belongs to different terminal (from terminal 5 to 3). If I have to change terminal at Heathrow, do I need to go through UK Border control ?
Thank you.

Comment: There is a bus that goes T5<->T3 that remains in the transit area.  You don't need to enter the UK.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you should follow the purple signs to Flight Connections and then take the free bus to Terminal 3. You will not need to enter the UK or clear customs.